# Can we update $timeout in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-timeout

Following is what I'm trying to do. When the first timeout is forcibly cancelled, I want to initiate the second timeout function, without the lag that already exists, had the timeout not been cancelled.

```js
$scope.data1_timeout = $timeout(function() {
  // some action
}, 2000);

$scope.data2_timeout = $timeout(function() {
  // some action
}, 4000);

$scope.show = function() {
  if (some action) {
    $timeout.cancel($scope.data1_timeout); //works perfectly fine
    //But how do I update data2_timeout so that the action inside it occurs just after data1_timeout is cancelled in this block.
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean if the 2000ms timer is cancelled, you want to call the 4000ms timer's callback function, but immediately?

Comment: call `$scope.data2_timeout` after cancel action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy doing by cancel both `$timeout`'s and call your function manually. Keep it simple =).

```
$scope.data1_timeout = $timeout(function() {
  // some action
}, 2000);

$scope.data2_timeout = $timeout(function() {
  myAction();
}, 4000);

$scope.show = function() {
  if (some action) {
    $timeout.cancel($scope.data1_timeout);
    $timeout.cancel($scope.data2_timeout);
    myAction();
  }
}

function myAction () {
  console.log('done');
}
```

Comment: Better yet, why not declare `myAction` at the top and make it the 2nd timer's callback?

Comment: @tavnab 1) No need to declare on top. This doesn't make sense at all. 2) Timers don't have a callback, `$timeout`'s uses `promises`. Please read the doc -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout.

Comment: 1) It's clearer to declare it at the top for readability, so you know what you're calling. 2) I'm sorry if I wan't clear. What I meant was that you can just do `$scope.data2_timeout = $timeout(myAction, 4000);` with no need for the extra wrapping function.

Comment: Timers do have a callback, the callback is what's executed after the elapsed time. The promise is what is returned.

Comment: @ste2425 its a function which is executed delayed not a `callback` in the original way of thinking. This is indeed a difference.

Comment: @lin we're talking specifically about the 1st argument to `$timeout`. That is a function, and what I'm referring to as the callback..

Comment: @tavnab yep I know and its still not a `callback` function, its a function which is executed delayed. The main properties of an `callback` function are not present while using `$timeout`. =)

Comment: @lin fair enough; in any case, that 1st argument to the second `$timeout` can just be `myAction` :)

Comment: @tavnab yea I know. I always keep the answer code closly to the questions code. Thank you.

Comment: @lin Thanks, Simplest fix. Worked like a charm. But still wanted to know if there's some tweak we could perform with the $timeout timer itself instead of cancelling it.

Comment: @Siena this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the promise returned by `$timeout` which gets rejected when the `$timeout` is canceled. The catch handler rejects the second timer and performs its actions immediately.

```
$scope.data1_timeout = $timeout(function() {
  // some action
}, 2000);

$scope.data2_timeout = $timeout(function() {
  // some action
}, 4000);

$scope.data1_timeout.catch(function(){
    $timeout.cancel($scope.data2_timeout);
    //same actions here as in data2_timeout
})
```

It'd make more sense to encapsulate the data2_timeout functionality in a named function and call it from both places like so:

```
$scope.data1_timeout = $timeout(function() {
  // some action
}, 2000);

function someAction2() {
    //some action
}

$scope.data2_timeout = $timeout(someAction2, 4000);

$scope.data1_timeout.catch(function(){
    $timeout.cancel($scope.data2_timeout);
    someAction2();
})
```

Note: If the intent is for data2 actions to wait for data1_timeout to complete or be canceled, then instead of data2 being a timeout, just add it as a `.finally()` callback for the data1_timeout promise.

```
$scope.data1_timeout = $timeout(function() {
  // some action
}, 2000);

$scope.data1_timeout.finally(function() {
  // do data2 stuff here.
  // Guaranteed to run, after data1_timeout completes or is canceled.
});
```